# BSD conjecture for rank 1 elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve. The weak Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer (BSD) conjecture predicts that
$$\text{ord}_{s=1}L(E, s)=\text{rank} E(\mathbb{Q}).$$
Thanks to the work of Gross-Zagier and Kolyvagin, we know that this conjecture is true if $\text{ord}_{s=1}L(E, s)\le 1$.

My question is: what is known in the case $\text{rank} E(\mathbb{Q})\le 1$? Has the BSD conjecture been proved under this assumption?

Thank you!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309086

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but only with the additional assumption that $ Ш(E/\mathbf{Q})$ is finite (one actually only needs that $Ш(E/\mathbf{Q})[p^\infty]$ is finite for almost any prime $p$). This then implies that $\mathrm{Sel}_{p^\infty}(E/\mathbf{Q})$ has corank 1, and then it follows from work of [Skinner](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7294), [Skinner-Zhang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1099), and [Zhang](http://math.mit.edu/~wz2113/math/online/Kconj.pdf).